# Time stamps for In[] and Out[]

Tags: front-end, date-and-time, interface

Once a command is entered and numbered, as in In[n], and an output is produced, as in Out[n], is it possible to find the time at which each one was done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Cell | Show Expression`from the menu to see the time stamps associated with a cell. If you want to do this programmatically, you could use [`Cells`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cells) and [`CurrentValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CurrentValue):

```
timeStamps[line_] := With[
    {
    cells = Pick[
        Cells[],
        CurrentValue[Cells[], CellLabel],
        _String?(StringMatchQ[__~~"["~~ToString[line]~~"]"~~___~~"="])
    ]
    },

    AssociationThread[
        CurrentValue[cells, CellLabel],
        DateString /@ Max /@ CurrentValue[cells, CellChangeTimes]
    ]
]
```

An example. Set the line number:

```
$Line = 1;
```

Then evaluate something:

```
2 + 2
```

> 4

Get time stamps:

```
timeStamps[2]
```

> <|"In[2]:=" -> "Tue 4 Dec 2018 19:49:43", 
>    "Out[2]=" -> "Tue 4 Dec 2018 19:49:43"|>

Comment: Unfortunately `CellChangeTimes` returns only *editing times*, not the evaluation time. It isn't correct to associate the last editing time with the time of assigning the `In[_]` label to input cell...